# Delete Views From A ViewPager Adapter?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

How to delete all views from a `ViewPager`?

I have to delete all views because in `OnDestroy()` of `Fragment` I have to stop a timer kinda feature so ultimately I have to remove all the views from the `PagerAdapter`.

Is there any method to get all the views and remove it from the adapter?

Remember, my pager returns views not fragments.

Please share your ideas.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    if(mPager != null) {

        if(mPager.getPagerAdapter() != null) {

            // Something here so that i can remove all the views and get my work done to stop the timers in my views.

         }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.